# OneToMany relationship not working in NHibernate and NET Persistence API

Tags: c#, nhibernate, c#-4.0, persistence

I am using the combination of Hibernate & NET Persistence API with C#. I have following relationship between two entities:

```
public class Question
{
    [OneToMany(Cascade = new CascadeType[] { CascadeType.ALL }, Fetch = FetchType.LAZY, MappedBy = "Question")]
    public virtual List<QueueLog> QueueLogs { get; set; }    
}
```

AND

```
public class QueueLog
{
    [ManyToOne (Fetch = FetchType.EAGER, TargetEntity = typeof(Question))]
    [Column(Name = "question_id", Nullable = false)]
    public virtual List<Question> Question { get; set; }
}
```

But while fetching question by its primary key ID, I am getting following error:

```
Missing column: Question_0 in Kmasters.dbo.queue_log
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: NHibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: Question_0 in Kmasters.dbo.queue_log
```

Also, I have tried making the relationship between the two entities in following way:

```
public class Question
{
    [OneToMany(Cascade = new CascadeType[] { CascadeType.ALL }, Fetch = FetchType.LAZY)]
    [JoinColumn(Name = "question_id", ReferencedColumnName = "id")]
    public virtual List<QueueLog> QueueLogs { get; set; }    
}
```

AND

```
public class QueueLog
{
    [ManyToOne (Fetch = FetchType.EAGER, TargetEntity = typeof(Question))]
    [Column(Name = "question_id", Nullable = false)]
    public virtual List<Question> Question { get; set; }
}
```

but still I am getting the same error. Can anyone please suggest me the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the code by making following changes:

```
public class Question
{
   [OneToMany(TargetEntity = typeof(QueueLog), MappedBy = "question", Fetch = FetchType.EAGER, Cascade = new CascadeType[] { CascadeType.ALL })]
   public virtual NHibernate.Collection.PersistentBag QueueLogs { get; set; }
}
```

AND

```
public class QueueLog
{
     [ManyToOne (Fetch = FetchType.EAGER, TargetEntity = typeof(Question))]
     [JoinColumn(Name = "question_id")]
     public virtual Question question { get; set; }
}
```